# In S1:E17 of the Clone Wars, why did the Separatist Alliance fund the creation of a virus capable of killing ALL life forms in the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

In Season 1, episode 17 of the Clone Wars, a scientist creates an aerosolized version of the Blue Shadow Virus, a virus that kills ALL species. The scientist plans to release this virus throughout the galaxy.

Given the Separatist Alliance is a part of the galaxy, and that its own members would (presumably) suffer the same fate as Republic citizens if the virus were to be released throughout the galaxy (IIRC, the Republic military shut the whole thing down), why would the Alliance fund such an endeavor? Like was it, "As long as we kill you, we don't care about killing ourselves in the process" or was it due to a belief in droid supremacy (killing off enough organic life forms so the droids themselves would dominate)?

Comment: Because they're eeeevil.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but if I were a government and some dude wanted me to fund a weapon to kill literally everyone on Earth, I'd tell him to go pound sand. The point of a war is, ostensibly, to WIN. It's not really a win if you blow yourself up, it's a suicide bombing.

Comment: Okay everyone, make sure no-one tells @moonman239 about nuclear weapons.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I know about MAD. Releasing this virus isn't "I don't care if you kill me, as long I get to kill you." This is "I'll kill myself if it means killing you, too."

Comment: @moonman239 If you’re either a certifiably-insane nihilistic psychopath or the only one who controls yourself and anyone you choose being able to transfer your life essence into new clone bodies, is that _really_ all that much of an issue, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dr. Vindi was a nihilist sociopath who believed only the Blue Shadow Virus should exist

The official Star Wars Databank entry for the Blue Shadow Virus [confirms that](https://www.starwars.com/databank/blue-shadow-virus):

> Vindi considered the virus a perfect organism, and imagined a galaxy where it was the only living thing, having killed everything else.

Dr. Vindi’s dreams were ultimately facilitated at the highest level of the Separatists by the Dark Lord of the Sith, Darth Sidious, a thoroughly evil individual who had no qualms about developing a weapon that would kill all life in the galaxy as long as it assisted in wiping out the Jedi, and who also had arguably better resources and access to the means of recreating the antidote in case Vindi’s weapon became a threat to the Sith domination of the galaxy. Recall Sidious’ whole prequel trilogy goal was essentially to engineer a galaxy-wide war just for the sole purpose of ending the Jedi; in this regard and as a Sith Lord, Sidious has little care for any of the denizens of the galaxy on either side of the war so long as the Jedi get to die.

Comment: Does the good doctor know that a virus by definition uses host cells as part of its life cycle, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

Probably for the same reason that weapons of mass destruction (nuclear bomb) are funded. The intention is to weaponise and use it against your enemies. It doesn't really matter that the weapons are indiscriminate and would also affect your allies if targeted that way.

Nuvo Vindi going "rogue" is presumably outside of the plan of the Separatists.